# An Exercise in "Measure Theory"

Tags: measure-theory

I have seen this on a wesite:

> **The boundary of a bounded set is of Lebesgue measure 0 if and only if it is of Jordan measure 0.**

as a proof: The above result can be proved directly using the Heine-Borel theorem.

I do not know how this can be follows.

Comment: Perhaps prove that this boundary is a closed set, and that a bounded closed set is of Lebesgue measure zero if and only if it is of Jordan measure zero.

Comment: How a bounded closed is of Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: Prove two things.  (1) The boundary of a set is a closed set, and (2) a bounded closed set is of Lebesgue measure zero if and only if it is of Jordan measure zero

Comment: @GEdgar I got your point, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As GEdgar indicated, the problem boils down to the fact that the boundary of a bounded set (in a Euclidean space) is compact. Therefore, any open cover of the boundary has a finite subcover; in particular, the existence of a countable cover with small total volume implies the existence of finite cover with small total volume.